# FOR cycle just including closure still displays only the last picture

Tags: javascript

Good evening,
I have many articles on my web (my own do-it-yourself manuals how to create...) interspersed with pictures (it is written in Czech language). These pictures are small and I want using onclick in html to display them bigger always close to those small. I.e. each bigger picture is to be displayed beside his small one. This is a practical illustration:
http://mix.zlatberry.cz/obrazky1.html (clicking on the big picture - unintentionally at the end of site - it is shut down).
But, clicking any small picture only the last big picture is displayed! 
Currently I know that only so called closure is remedy for my problem but despite this trick I am not able to force my iteration to show the first big picture beside the first small one, the second big picture beside the second small one and so on and so on.

HTML (is not from my head). Btw, please, is it posible to write this code - small picture versus big picture - easier way??

```js
let obr = new Array('velka-fotka1', 'velka-fotka2', 'velka-fotka3', 'velka-fotka4', 'velka-fotka5');

for (let i = 0; i < obr.length; i++) {
  (function() {
    let x = i;
    let fotka = document.getElementById(obr[x]);

    function ZobrazFotku() {
      fotka.style.display = 'block';
    }
    document.write(x); //document.write(x) writes numbers 01234
    function SchovatFotku(div) {
      document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'none';
    }
  })();
}
```

```html
<div id='velka-fotka1'>
  <div class="foto">
    <a href='#' onclick="SchovatFotku('velka-fotka1'); return false" title='Shut down'></a>
    <img src='bigmotopelech1.jpg' alt='click for display small picture' onclick="SchovatFotku('velka-fotka1'); return false" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="foto">
  <a onclick="ZobrazFotku('bigmotopelech1.jpg');  return false" href='bigmotopelech1.jpg' title='display the big picture'><img src='motopelech1.jpg' width="320" height="240" alt="Pneumatika z motorky a deka"></a>
</div>
```

Testing my closure I tried to add document.write(x) but numbers are listed TOGETHER, not one after another by clicking small pictures, and all big pictures are displayed, to make thing worse,  in a separate window of browser:
http://mix.zlatberry.cz/obrazky2.html

So I am really at the end of my tether :-( . I try to solve it since September.
I will be very appreciative for help leading to solving my problem. I enjoy to modify all my websites this way and I am in the doldrums... 
Many thanks in advance <3
HTML:

```
<div id='big-photo1'>
<div class="foto">
<a href='#' onclick="HidePhoto('big-photo1'); return false" title='Hide'></a>
<img src='bigmotopelech1.jpg' alt='click for display a small photo' onclick="HidePhoto('big-photo1'); return false" />
</div>
</div>  

<div class="foto">
<a onclick="DisplayPhoto('bigmotopelech1.jpg');  return false" href='bigmotopelech1.jpg' title='display a big photo'><img src='motopelech1.jpg' width="320" height="240" alt="Pneumatika z motorky a deka"></a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
let picture = new Array('big-photo1', 'big-photo2', 'big-photo3', 'big-photo4', 'big-photo5'); 

for (let i = 0; i < picture.length; i++)    { 
(function()  { 
let x = i;  
let photo = document.getElementById(picture[x]);         
function DisplayPhoto()  {                                  
photo.style.display = 'block'; 
                        }
function HidePhoto(div){  
    document.getElementById(div).style.display='none';
                      }                                                   
})();                          
  }
```

Here is link with English variables etc.  http://mix.zlatberry.cz/pict1.html

Comment: Your question proves why it is such an incredibly bad practice to use non-English variable and function names. At least my brain completely refuses to even bother checking your code because of (probably Czech) foreign variable and function names.

Answer (score 0):

Change your ZobrazFotku function to accept the id of the div in which the `img` is contained as the first argument. This way you don't need the `for` loop at all.

```
function ZobrazFotku(id) {
  var div = document.getElementById(id);
  div.style.display = 'block';
}
function SchovatFotku(div) {
  document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'none';
}
```

JSFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rkaqzx2v/

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! I have tried it: http://mix.zlatberry.cz/obrazky3.html  but the big pictures are still displayed in a separate window...

Comment: I am thinking about why your "JSFiddle" do some work but the same script on my website http://mix.zlatberry.cz/obrazky3.html is no-functional... ?